# How to prove that $ab-\sqrt{a^2-1}\sqrt{b^2-1}\geq1$, when $a\geq1,b\geq1$?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

## How to prove that $ab-\sqrt{a^2-1}\sqrt{b^2-1}\geq1$, when $a\geq1,b\geq1$？

I tried to use
$$
\sqrt{ab}\leq\frac{1}{2}(a+b),
$$
but end up with
$$
ab-\sqrt{a^2-1}\sqrt{b^2-1}\geq ab-\frac{1}{2}(a^2-1+b^2-1)=1-\frac{1}{2}(a-b)^2.
$$
How to prove this inequalities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $a = \frac{1}{2}(s+\frac{1}{s})$, $b = \frac{1}{2}(t+ \frac{1}{t})$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\require{cancel}\;(ab-1)^2 \ge (a^2-1)(b^2-1) \iff \cancel{a^2b^2} - 2ab + \bcancel{1} \ge \cancel{a^2b^2} - a^2 - b^2 + \bcancel{1}\,$.

Answer (score 0):

The same idea as orangeskid :

$$\cosh x\cosh y-\sinh x \sinh y=\cosh(x-y)\geq 1.$$